# Correct way to inferring return type by using `infer`

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I want to determine the return type from input values like the following code:

```js
type Return<S> = {
    array: S extends 'number' ? number[] : S extends 'string' ? string[] : never;
    value: S extends 'number' ? number : S extends 'string' ? string : S extends 'object' ? object : never;
}

type F = {
    array: (_: 'number' | 'string') => void,
    value: (_: 'number' | 'string' | 'object') => void
};

function test<
    T extends 'array' | 'value',
    S extends F[T] extends (_: infer Arg) => void ? Arg: never
>(t: T, s: S): Return<S>[T] {}

() => {
    const x1 = test('array', 'number') // string[] | number[]
    const x2 = test<'array', 'number'>('array', 'number') // number[]

    const y1 = test('value', 'number') // string | number | object
    const y2 = test<'value', 'number'>('value', 'number') // number
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAShwFcBOA7APAZQHxQLxQG8BYAKCnKgEMklKQAuKDKCAD2AhQBMBnKAchQIAtgCMISflAD8UIWIkBtALpRGzNh259+PYEgCWKAOZTZewyZVq5EAG4SA3KQpQ7lADYII6lu068AvLikjJyIiE2Gv7aAhZGpmHxJlF+WoH8APaiAFYQAMbAZlDZeYU2KPZOpAC+pKSgkFAAYniELhTUtAxQABQA+oyCERJSAD5x+gn8AJR4OHaZBlwANB3k7l4+fYNBI6ETulMm4wKlBUVzuAtLXLXOJKQAZggohQaZKFAcemjrUAAVNIBHRdOinfibbz8NZkCjRdJ8ZqKAGqTQgnaMIxPCRQACCSGMVxuyzCBOMjEqDiQpCwvWAjABKygPHUM0YcEQqEwWBRqgIdUeJF6xPacPI+U+eigrAAjG0fsBevwwSAYXsFJI5gB6bUs47GawTYJKZT-SUoaWsABMCogvxVNHBzOGmv4dMd3XVrpCsyguvCmpU9XFUAt0pA8vwiuVUIg3pNWv9euSxigxv26ZKuQu5qlwCgIFt0ftwDQkM80Jdifdscr8er+z9AcTtVIQA)

In the above code, I want to determine the second argument's type and the return type from the first argument.

There is type `F`, which means some mutation functions for the second argument. So I got the second argument's type from `F`'s argument by using the `infer` keyword.

However, as you can see, the compiler cannot infer the return type of `x1` and `y1`. Is there a way to make the compiler can infer generics from the second argument?

Answer (score 0):

We can make it a bit less verbose with the `Parameters` utility type. This fixes the problem (although I am not sure why).

```
function test<
    T extends 'array' | 'value',
    S extends Parameters<F[T]>[0]
>(t: T, s: S): Return<S>[T] {}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAShwFcBOA7APAZQHxQLxQG8BYAKCnKgEMklKQAuKDKCAD2AhQBMBnKAchQIAtgCMISflAD8UIWIkBtALpRGzNh259%20PYEgCWKAOZTZewyZVq5EAG4SA3KQpQ7lADYII6lu068AvLikjJyIiE2Gv7aAhZGpmHxJlF%20WoH8APaiAFYQAMbAZlDZeYU2KPZOpAC%20pKSgkFAAYniELhTUtAxQABQA%20oyCERJSAD5x%20gn8AJR4OHaZBlwANB3k7l4%20fYNBI6ETulMm4wKlBUVzuAtLXLXOJKQAZggohQaZKFAcemjrUAAVNIBHRdOinfibbz8NZkCjRdJ8AAK1EowngEh4aGaigByiwigADMpSFhesBGACVlAeOoZow4IhUJgCXj2nDyEh4MgvgQalQ%20JQUCBavUSL0rjhiByoPlPnooKwAIxtH7AXr8MEgGF7BSSOYAegNNOOxmsE2CShJMrlKAVrAATKqIL9NTRwdThnr%20GS3d0dV6QrMoEbwnqVGLXLaFSAVfg1RqoRAA%20dCsHQ8ljFALftsyVchd-tHgFAQE74y7gGhIZ5oZ7LZJfUmAw308aG6KSEA)